# Java Program Unable to Write Sqlite DB inside Windows Program Files

Tags: java, windows, sqlite

I have created a java program which reads and writes sqlite db.
It runs without any problems but the issue i am facing is after creating a installer using inno setup. After installing the software inside "c:/Program Files/MyProgram" the program executes but it can only read the db file and cannot write it. Please guide me where i'm going wrong.

Note: 
 1. The location of database is inside MyProgram Folder.
 2. I have created .exe file using launch4j
 3. MyProgram folder contains only 3 files a) program.exe b) sqlite.db c) libs (folder)

Thank You In Advance :)

Comment: please add your code to your post. Do your best to create a *minimal* example that allows to reproduce the issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's only the security features from Windows, nothing wrong with your Program.
Inno setup and your program should store the sqlite-db in e.g. %AppData% and not under c:/Program Files/

Comment: Thank You Very Much ralf.w. 
Now my program runs without any problem.

But if you don't mind i would like to ask how to bypass this security features? :)

Comment: @Kuntal Adak: I did try to set the security permissions, but windows does intervine, so that did not function at all, I would just try another folder.